# React: how to overwrite state

Tags: reactjs

Usually when we `setState`, we want to merge some new state with old state. I have a use case where I want to overwrite old state. Is there any clean way to do this?

For example, suppose my current state has 561 different attributes. I want the new state to have 3 attributes. Do I have to iterate all the attributes in a for-loop and call `setState` 561 times to delete each of them individually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no clean way, reassigning `this.state` after component construction is considered a bad practice.

As it's suggested in the question, a state is supposed to be cleaned up by iterating over its keys:

```
setState(prevState => {
  const state = {};
  for (let key in prevState)
    state[key] = undefined;
  ...
  return state;
});
```

If there are too many properties to process, this likely means that a state was initially structured in inefficient way.

Comment: I imagine this is more efficient than calling `setState` multiple times.